# Get key of an element from Firebase database snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the next query for a Firebase database

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+userId+ubication)
    .orderByChild('timestamp')
    .equalTo(parseInt(timeStamp))
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot=>{
        console.log(snapshot);
    }
);
```

This query return my only one element, I need remove this element from the database but I don't know how I can get the key of it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general practice, when you obtain a snapshot that has children, you can access them using the `forEach` loop. Following this, you can get the key from the child element using `.key`. This can be done regardless of the number of child elements the query returns.

You can do something like this :-

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+userId+ubication)
    .orderByChild('timestamp')
    .equalTo(parseInt(timeStamp))
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot=>{
        console.log(snapshot);
        var arrayOfKeys = []
        snapshot.forEach(function(child_element){
        arrayOfKeys.push(child_element.key)
    })
}
);
```

For deleting a child element, you can now reference the path using the key. Additionally, I would strongly recommend you to thoroughly understand `Promises` and asynchronous calls, because they are essentially important when you're dealing with lists of data in node.js!